# What to provide for "Information needed for business model and users" review error

Tags: ios, app-store

While releasing an App on App Store, I got this as one of the review notes

[image: App Store Review note]

I don't understand what I need to do? I tried reading the document they have linked, but it also says nothing about what you should do.

For example, I understand my app shouldn't be available for everyone, but I can't unlist it before they actually approve it.

And I don't know how the Apple Business Manager works? Is it a separate iOS app? Or is it part of App Store on iOS?

Comment: Can you answer the bullet questions and reply to them

Comment: It sounds like Apple doesn't think that your app is suitable for general availability on the App Store, but it may be and they want to understand more. My company has a client app for an enterprise SaaS service, but because it is installed by employees of numerous organisations on their personal phones, it is in the App Store. An app that has a more limited audience may be better as a custom app or unlisted app.

Comment: Apple Business Manager is a free web-based service that organisations can make use of. You can make your app available to selected organisations as a custom app via ABM. The company purchases your app via ABM and distributes it to their employees. It can be free via ABM and the organisation can pay you directly.

Comment: And if you are going to distribute it as an unlisted app, you can, and must, register it as unlisted before it is approved.

Comment: @unobatbayar There is no place to answer these questions. I tried putting them in the "Review Notes" but they don't seem to care.

Comment: @Paulw11 For Apple Business Manager, I think that requires organizations? But we're only working with companies here, not huge private organizations

Comment: Any company with a DUNS number can register for Apple Business Manager, but you may find it is better as an unlisted app - https://developer.apple.com/support/unlisted-app-distribution/ or you may be able to add it to the store. Our saas app client is in the store and our client organisations range in size from 300 to 3000 users. If your app is in rejected state then there should be a way you can reply to that message in the app review section for your app in App Store Connect